# Check if class object

Tags: python

Is it possible in python to check if an object is a class object. IE if you have

```
class Foo(object):
    pass
```

How could you check if o is Foo (or some other class) or an instance of Foo (or any other class instance)? In Java this would be a simple matter. Just check if the object is an instance of Class. Is there something similar in python or are you supposed to just not care?

Slight clarification: I'm trying to make a function that prints information about the parameter its given. So if you pass in o, where o = Foo() it prints out information about Foo. If you pass in Foo it should print out the exact same information. Not information about Type.

Comment: Sometimes, you should try not to care about the exact type, but rather does the object support the interface you require. See "duck typing". If I call your function with something that behaves exactly like a `Foo`, why reject my call? Occasionally, however, you do need to know if an object is and instance, and see the answers for that.

Comment: "I'm trying to see if its an instance or a class. Not just if its an instance of a specific class." Everything is an instance, including classes. Classes instances of `type`, i.e., `instance(Foo, type) == True`. You could pick them out that way, but that's not normally needed.

Comment: You are not supposed to care. People shouldn't shove square pegs into circle holes. If they try, there will be a pretty obvious Exception raised, and as a programmer you should document so as to prevent other people from trying it in the first place.

Comment: I got it working with a slight variation on Thanatos' suggestion. Checking for if its an instance of type or types.ClassType to support old style objects. Thanks for the help guys! I appreciate it!

Comment: Most of the time, if you're trying to determine whether something is a Class (which in Python means just it's an instance of `type`), you would be better served by just writing the common case, throwing a `try`-`except` around it, and then handling other "exceptional" behavior. Better to beg forgiveness than ask permission, especially if the alternative is something ugly like checking if an object is a `type`. `try: newobj = o(); except Exception as e: newobj = o #o may not be a class (or function)`

Answer (score 10):

Use the `isinstance` builtin function.

```
>>> o = Foo()
>>> isinstance(o, Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(13, Foo)
False
```

This also works for subclasses:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo): pass

>>> b = Bar()
>>> isinstance(b, Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(b, Bar)
True
```

Yes, normally, you are supposed to not particularly care what type the object is. Instead, you just call the method you want on `o` so that people can plug in arbitrary objects that conform to your interface. This wouldn't be possible if you were to aggressively check the types of objects that you're using. This principle is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and allows you a bit more freedom in how you choose to write your code.

Python is pragmatic though, so feel free to use `isinstance` if it makes sense for your particular program.

Edit:

To check if some variable is a class vs an instance, you can do this:

```
>>> isinstance(Foo, type)   # returns true if the variable is a type.
True
>>> isinstance(o, type)
False
```

Comment: My end goal is to make a function that prints out information about an object if its an instance and print something different if its a class. So this time I do care.

Answer (score 3):

> My end goal is to make a function that prints out information about an object if its an instance and print something different if its a class. So this time I do care.

First, understand that classes *are* instances — they're instances of type:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
...
>>> isinstance(Foo, type)
True
```

So, you can pick out classes that way, but keep in mind that classes are instances too. (And thus, you can pass classes to functions, return them from functions store them in lists, create the on the fly…)

Answer (score 2):

the isinstance() function

```
isinstance(o, Foo)
```

and you can also use it to compare `o` to `object`

```
In [18]: class Foo(object): pass

In [20]: o_instance = Foo()

In [21]: o_class = Foo

In [22]: isinstance(o_instance, Foo)
Out[22]: True

In [23]: isinstance(o_class, Foo)
Out[23]: False

In [24]: isinstance(o_instance, object)
Out[24]: True

In [25]: isinstance(o_class, object)
Out[25]: True
```

Comment: It's gotta work for any class object. Not just Foo. And I'm trying to see if its an instance or a class. Not just if its an instance of a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do like Thanatos said and check
    isinstance(Foo, type)
But in the case of old class types you have to also do
    isinstance(Foo, types.ClassType)